# How to list properties of built-in functions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, built-in

When I define an object I can reach all its properties by using the dot character and the same applies to built-in functions like String, Array, Math, etc.
But I cannot loop through them by using `for(# in #` for example. It says String is native code but still I can reach all its members albeit I cannot iterate through them. 
I know `window` is iterable but their 'sub-functions' appear to be not. 
Why is that? Is there a chance to call the properties without explicitly typing their names in? Can I list all its members somehow?

I am aware of that It does not look useful and no one would need it in production. I am asking it because I could not do it and I hope someone can give me some help.

Comment: How would you call a member function without knowing its name ? That's king of stupid. If you want to call a function when you only have a String (representing the function's name), juste do object[str]();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all names only of own(!!!) properties

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(YOUR_OBJECT)
```

It means, this method doesn't enumerate inherited properties. And if you want to enumerate inherited properties you can use `YOUR_OBJECT.__proto__`, but it works only in Mozilla

Comment: @Bergi How would you get a list of the prototypes with this method?

Comment: `for (var prototypes=[], p=YOUR_OBJECt; p=Object.getPrototypeOf(p); prototypes.push(p));` should do it. No difference in functionality to getting `__proto__`, except for being standard.

Comment: @Bergi but you have to stop youe loop when p will equal Object, because `Object.getPrototypeOf(Object) == function() {}` and you have infinite loop

Comment: No, you've got something wrong there. `Object -> Function.prototype -> Object.prototype -> null`. Prototype chains are guaranteed to have no circles, so this cannot be an infinite loop.

Comment: getPrototypeOf only returns 16 properties while getOwnPropertyNames lists all of them

Comment: @Bálint Juhász `getPrototypeOf` returns only prototypes, and after that you have to call `getOwnPropertyNames()` for every prototype.